# Ansible split string into n number of variable

Tags: ansible

I have to update a config file with server IPs from a cluster. The cluster contains minimum 2 servers, however, the maximum number of servers in the cluster is unknown. I want to collect the IPs as a delimited list IP1|IP2|IPn and split them into separate variables.
The below snippet is working fine with two variables.

```yaml
  - name: Configure ACL
    lineinfile:
      path: /server.xml
      insertafter: '<Valve className="org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve" directory="logs" prefix="localhost_access_log" suffix=".txt" pattern="%h %l %u %t &quot;%r&quot; %s %b"/>\n'
      line: '<Valve className=\"org.apache.catalina.valves.RemoteAddrValve\" allow=\"{{ip1}}|{{ip2}}\"\ />'
```

Questions:

1. How can I split a collected string into separate variables?
2. How can I generalize the above insert to n number of IPs?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With a list of comma delimited IP addresses (YAML) such as:

```yaml
ips: 1.1.1.1,2.2.2.2,3.3.3.3
```

You can use the Python `split` method in your Jinja2 templating to obtain a list:

```
{{ ips.split(',') }}
```

And template it out with the `join` Jinja2 filter:

```yaml
  - name: Configure ACL
    vars:
      ip_list: "{{ ips.split(',') }}"
    lineinfile:
      path: /server.xml
      insertafter: '<Valve className="org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve" directory="logs" prefix="localhost_access_log" suffix=".txt" pattern="%h %l %u %t &quot;%r&quot; %s %b"/>\n'
      line: '<Valve className=\"org.apache.catalina.valves.RemoteAddrValve\" allow=\"{{ ip_list|join('|') }}\"\ />'
```

The `join` filter takes 1 argument, which is the character to delimit each item in the list in the output of the template.

Line output:

```
<Valve className=\"org.apache.catalina.valves.RemoteAddrValve\" allow=\"1.1.1.1|2.2.2.2|3.3.3.3\"\ />
```